# File as a resource not being embedded

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I added a binary file as a resource in my assembly (class library). The `Persistence` property is disabled and it's set to `Linked at compile time`.

The file has also been added under the `Resources folder` and I can change its properties. I set the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`.

I then try to get the resource by doing:

```
var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("myfile.bin")
```

However, stream is `null`.

I then changed the `Build Action` to `None` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. On build the file is not copied.

What I actually need is to have the file embedded in the assembly and accessed as shown above.

What am I missing?

Comment: The resource name starts with namespace. If you are unsure, just check assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() for the conplete list. You can actually use this and look for the one that ends with your resource name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add your file to the project (not as anything special. Just select "Add existing item" and pick your file.)
- Pick "Embedded Resource" as the build action of that file.
- Call assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() for debugging once to find out the name that you need to use (it contains the namespace and some more stuff)
- proceed with `var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(`  name you got from the debug call `)`